# Deriving insights, such as average session duration, from a series of timestamped events

Tags: sql, postgresql, analytics

We have a group of events that we capture and store in our Postgres database. For the sake of simplicity, below is an example:

| id | event_name | user | event_datetime |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | View Project | Bob | 2023-05-01 12:03 |
| 2 | Visit Homepage | Bob | 2023-05-01 12:12 |
| 3 | Edit Profile | Ashley | 2023-05-01 12:15 |
| 4 | View Project | Bob | 2023-05-01 12:25 |
| 5 | View Project | Jack | 2023-05-01 12:26 |
| 6 | Invite User | Bob | 2023-05-01 12:28 |
| 7 | Perform Search | Jack | 2023-05-01 12:28 |
| 8 | Submit Ticket | Bob | 2023-05-01 12:29 |
| 9 | Perform Search | Bob | 2023-05-01 12:55 |
| 10 | Perform Search | Ashley | 2023-05-01 12:59 |

Based on these events, we're trying to gain some insights into user engagement. Specifically, we want to find out the average session duration and the average number of of sessions for a user or a group of users. For our purposes, we define a "session" as any 10 minute interval where the user performs actions. If after a specific action X, they don't perform another action for 10 minutes or longer, we consider action X to be the last action of that session, and any subsequent action is the first action of the next session, and so on.

For example, based on the above table, we see that Bob viewed a project at 12:03, then nine minutes later he visited the homepage. But then his next action did not occur until 12:25 - so there was essentially a session timeout. Then the same thing happened at 12:29, after which he didn't do anything until 12:55. So during the 12:00 - 1:00 interval, he has had three distinct sessions, whereas Jack has had one, and Ashley has had two.

Based on the above criteria, what would the queries be that would return:

- Average session duration for a user (or group of users)
- Average number of sessions
- Most common activities per session, e.g. how many "perform search" activities per session are being done by a group that consists of Jack and Ashley

This isn't a subject we're familiar with, so if we need to take a different strategy (e.g. create another table/view with these derived statistics and then query that), I'd be happy to red more about that too.

Answer (score 0):

Using a `cte` to produce session groups and aggregation at the end:

```
with recursive cte(user_name, id, dt, c_id) as (
    select e.user_name, min(e.id), min(e.event_datetime), min(e.id) from events e 
    group by e.user_name
    union all
    select c.user_name, e.id, e.event_datetime, case when extract(epoch from e.event_datetime - c.dt) > 600 then e.id else c.c_id end 
    from cte c join events e on e.user_name = c.user_name and 
        e.event_datetime = (select min(e1.event_datetime) from events e1 where e1.user_name = c.user_name and e1.event_datetime > c.dt)
),
session_events as (
    select c.user_name, c.c_id, e.event_name, count(*) e_c from cte c join events e on e.event_datetime = c.dt group by c.user_name, c.c_id, e.event_name
)
-- average session duration for certain users (specified in parenthesis)
select avg(t1.av) av_session_sec 
from (select t.user_name, avg(extract(epoch from t.m2 - t.m1)) av 
      from (select c.user_name, c.c_id, min(c.dt) m1, max(c.dt) m2 
            from cte c group by c.user_name, c.c_id) t 
      where t.user_name in ('Jack', 'Ashley', 'Bob')
      group by t.user_name) t1
-- average number of sessions
select avg(t.s_c) av_sessions from (select c.user_name, count(distinct c.c_id) s_c 
   from cte c group by c.user_name) t
-- Most common activity per session per group
select t.*, e1.event_name from (select e.user_name, e.c_id, max(e.e_c) m from session_events e group by e.user_name, e.c_id) t
join session_events e1 on e1.user_name = t.user_name and e1.e_c = t.m
where t.user_name in ('Jack', 'Ashley')
```

[See fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/Ldz_L7dN)

Comment: Thank you, I'll play with this to see if I can use it as a starting point. That said, the linked fiddle doesn't quite match what I meant. Rather than average session duration for each specific user as a new row, we would need the average session duration for the _group_ of given users. For example, for Bob and Ashley, it would be (260 + 0) / 2 = 130, whereas for Bob, Jack and Ashley it would be (260 + 120 + 0) / 3 = 126.66. We are looking to get a single average number in other words.

Comment: @EgeErsoz Please see my recent edit.